# prior probability vs a priori probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, terminology

What is the difference between "Prior probability" and "a priori probability"

Wikipedia have two distinct pages for them.

As of my inference i thought "Prior" and "a priori" are same, i.e., P(y) in Bayes' theorem

P(y,x) = P(x,y)P(y) / P(x)

Comment: As you've already found those two articles that discuss these concepts and even refer to one another, it would help if you explain what part of what they say about each other you don't understand.

Comment: I just read them. The article on 'a priori' looks to be a sparsely documented 'stub', while the Bayesian article on 'prior' seems authoritative--or at least in line with my own usage. I don't wonder that OP doesn't see the difference insisted upon in the 'a priori' article.

Comment: @joriki, in the context of speech recognition, I read some people to say the language model as `a priori` whihle other says `prior`. I thought they are interchangeable words, as @Bruce Trumbo mentioned. I don't understand what they link with philosophy, i don't know philosophy

Comment: @BruceTrumbo: But both articles make roughly the same distinction. The one that seems authoritative to you says "Not to be confused with a priori probability" at the top, and later in the text: "Some attempts have been made at finding [a priori probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_probability), i.e. probability distributions in some sense logically required by the nature of one's state of uncertainty.", which corresponds with the other article's "In particular, an 'a priori probability' is derived purely by deductive reasoning."

Comment: I don't know to what extent this distinction is actually made in how these terms are used; but the distinction between the broader concept of probabilities assigned before further data becomes available and the more specific concept of probabilities derived purely deductively without any data seems reasonably clear to be.

Comment: Maybe this is why the terms 'empirical Bayes' and 'subjective Bayes' are commonly used.

Comment: Never heard these terms before, Thanks @BruceTrumbo

Answer (score 3):

Some people make a philosophical distinction, which is (somewhat
fuzzily) mentioned in the Wikipedia article on 'a priori'. 
I agree with you that, for better or worse, the two terms are used
almost interchangeably in Bayesian statistics.

One difference in usage might be illustrated by the experiment
of rolling a die. You might decide 'a priori' that the dice
are fair, from which it follows that P(Even number) = 3/6 = 1/2.
This is not necessarily in a Bayesian framework. It is also
not very informative to say the decision is 'a prioi'. It would
be more helpful to say why you choose to believe the die is fair
(tradition, laziness, you've tested it a bit, you trust the
person who produced it, etc.).

It seems to me that the term 'prior' probability distribution is rarely, if ever,
seen outside of a Bayesian framework.

The German philosopher Arthur Schopenhauer is quoted as saying,
"Philosophy is the systematic abuse of a terminology established
just for that purpose" (my translation). I think he would have
enjoyed your observation about the two Wikipedia pages.

Perhaps someone else will educate us both with a more compelling
distinction between the two terms that makes sense to both of us.